# How to catch props from a single component that was rendered multiple times with different prop values

Tags: reactjs

In app.jsx I have rendered Inputfield component multiple times and passed a random value through Math.random(). I am looking to grab those random numbers that were passed through as a prop and add them in the Inputfield component. How can I approach this problem?

I currently have no clue how to approach and solve this problem.

Here are my codes-

app.jsx

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import styles from "./css/app.module.css";
import Inputbox from "./Inputbox";
function App() {
  const [components, setComponents] = useState([]);
  const boxCount = useRef(null);

  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      addComponent();
    }
  };
  function addComponent() {
    var result = boxCount.current.value;
    for (var i = 0; i < result; i++) {
      setComponents((arr) => [...arr, <Inputbox num={Math.random()} />]);
    }
    // setComponents(Inputbox);
    // console.log(result);
  }
  function checkAll() {}
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <input
        type="text"
        name=""
        id=""
        ref={boxCount}
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
        placeholder="Enter number of box"
      />
      <button onClick={addComponent}>Add TextBox</button>
      <button onClick={checkAll}>Check all</button>
      {/* <div>{components}</div> */}
      <div className={styles.componentList}>
        {components.map((jsxComponent) => (
          <div key={Math.random()}>{jsxComponent}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Inputbox,jsx

```
import styles from "./css/inputbox.module.css";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
const Inputbox = (props) => {
  const inputVal = useRef(null);
  console.log("Individual nums" + " " + props.num);
  console.log("Total");
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(true);
  const handleChk = () => {
    setChecked(!checked);
    if (checked == true) {
      handleChange();
    }
  };
  const handleChange = () => {
    var res = parseInt(inputVal.current.value);
    return res;
  };
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <input type="checkbox" onClick={handleChk} name="" id="" />
      <input type="text" ref={inputVal} placeholder="Enter numbers" />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Inputbox;
```

Comment: Don't store components in state. Store the values

Comment: Could you please elaborate about it a bit? I am a beginner. That would help me quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addComponent() {
  const result = boxCount.current.value;
  const newArr = []
  for (let i = 0; i < result; i++) {
    newArr.push(Math.random())
  }
  setComponents((arr) => [...arr, ...newArr]);
}
```

```
<div className={styles.componentList}>
  {components.map((value) => (
    <Inputbox num={value} key={value} />
  ))}
</div>
```